# Own Sms Application. How can I get data in ComposeSmsActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, android-manifest

I am trying to create my own SMS application. Everything is working fine, but I encountered a small problem. How can I get data like number, etc. in my activity, after someone click right there.

[image: Default contact application!]

My activity(ComposeSmsActivity) is opening correct. I would like to get data pass there so I can fill my EditText with number or open other activity. Couldn't find solution. I think it might be done by some intent or getScheme, but I don't know the 'Keys'. Hope you can help me.

```
 <!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
        <activity android:name=".ComposeSmsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:`enter code here`scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

@PS Solution

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
String base = uri.getSchemeSpecificPart();
int pos = base.indexOf('?');
String number = (pos == -1) ? base : base.substring(0, pos);
```

Comment: the data is likely in the `onNewIntent()` method of the activity. Set a breakpoint there and check which data you receive in intent extras

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution dosen't work. `onNewIntent()` does not trigger.

Comment: check the `onCreate()`  `getIntent()` also

Comment: There is no Extras in it, but log return this: **Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=smsto:xxxxxxxxxxxx cmp=com.vasco.smsapp/.activity.SendSmsActivity }**

Comment: isn't that what you need? the phone number. The other info is not passed I think (contact name, etc. But you can get it programmatically by the phone number)

Comment: Ok, so there is number, but how can I get it now? I am trying to `getIntent().getData()` but i can't find any intresting method that return the numer. geting extras with key "smsto" don't work either :/

Comment: `intent.getData();` will return `Uri`, which you likely should be able to parse somehow. I can't say exactly because i will take too much time for me to try it myself